# passing an argument to an object

Tags: php, phpexcel

to get cell from xls

```
$filename = "upload/" . $nfile;
$type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($type);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
$array = ($objPHPExcel->getSheetNames());
$finarr = [];
```

It's works.

To get value of cell from Excel by PHPExcel:

```
foreach($sheetNames as $singleSheetName => $value){
    $vz = ($objPHPExcel->getSheet($singleSheetName)->getCell('L40')->getCalculatedValue());
    return $firarr[$vz];
}
```

It's works.

I want to optimize code.
create a function

```
function getCorrectCell($a, $b) {
     return ($objPHPExcel->getSheet($a)->getCell($b)->getCalculatedValue());
};
```

I call
`getCorrectCell($singleSheetName, 'L40');`

error

Got error

> PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: objPHPExcel in /var/www/******/html/secondworker.php on line 13
> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function `getSheet()` on null

How to correctly declarate function and put arguments?
Thanks for help!

Comment: `$objPHPExcel` is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)